# Hide My Files from Another Application

Tags: android, file, hide

In my application i m downloading some (mp4 or mp3 ) files from the internet. Now i want to hide those files from any other application like(Astro any Music player) so how can i do this ?

Please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called ".nomedia" in the folder where you are storing your downloaded files. Well behaved apps should now ignore your content.

Comment: if anyone can remove this file from my that folder so i dont think so it is the proper way.. can you suggest me another better way?

Comment: But you asked for a method to hide your files, and that's the answer I gave. Any third-party apps which use MediaStore.Audio to search for audio content will honour ".nomedia". If you want a solution to actually secure your files, then maybe you need to ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

if you save the files in your application space, it will automatically be hidden from all other applications.

Comment: thanks for your answer farhan . but there is one problem in that.. because i download mp4 files and appxmatily that size is 7 to 10 mb.. so it increase the size of out application...

Comment: @Chirag: Then do not download the file. You cannot "hide" things on the SD card from anyone: users, other applications, other operating systems.